# NuxtServerInit sets Vuex auth state after reload

Tags: javascript, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm setting a basic authentication on a Nuxt project with JWT token and cookies to be parsed by `nuxtServerInit` function.

On login with email/password, works as intended, `setUser` mutation is triggered and the appropriate `user` object is stored in `state.auth.user`.

On reload, `nuxtServerInit` will get the jwt token from `req.headers.cookies`, call the `GET` method and identify user.Works like a charm.

Problem starts when I hit the `/logout` endpoint. `state.auth.user` is set to false and Im effectively logged out... but If I refresh, I'm logged in again with the previous user data. Even if my cookies are properly empty (on below code, both `user` and `cookie` are `undefined` after logout and refresh, as expected)

So I really don't get why is my `state.auth.user` is back to its initial value...

**store/index.js**

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import auth from "./modules/auth";
import axios from "~/plugins/axios";

const cookieparser = process.server ? require("cookieparser") : undefined;
const END_POINT = "api/users";


const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
     async nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch}, { req }) {
        let cookie = null;
        console.log(req.headers.cookie)
        if (req.headers.cookie) {
          const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie);
          try {
            cookie = JSON.parse(parsed.auth);
            console.log("cookie", cookie)
            const {accessToken} = cookie
            const config = {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
              }
            }
            const response = await axios.get(`${END_POINT}/current`, config)

            const user = response.data
            console.log("user nuxt server init", user)
            await commit('setUser', user)
          } catch (err) {
            // No valid cookie found
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    modules: {
      auth
    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

**modules/auth.js**

```
import axios from "~/plugins/axios";
const Cookie = process.client ? require("js-cookie") : undefined;
const END_POINT = "api/users";

export default {
  state: {
    user: null,
    errors: {}
  },
  getters: {
    isAuth: state => !!state.user
  },

  actions: {
    login({ commit }, payload) {
      axios
        .post(`${END_POINT}/login`, payload)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          const { user, accessToken } = data;
          const auth = { accessToken };
          Cookie.set("auth", auth);
          commit("setUser", user);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          const error = e;
          console.log(e);
          commit("setError", error);
        });
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
      axios
        .post(`${END_POINT}/logout`)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          Cookie.remove("auth");
          commit("setUser", false);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
    setError(state, errors) {
      state.errors = errors;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Found a workaround with a `if (req.headers.cookie) {...} else { commit('setUser', false) }` but I still find it weird this behaviour...

Comment: I'd say it's because you commit `setUser` under condition that `req.headers.cookie`. That object surely exists, so the serverInit proceeds to populate the user object. I think all you need to do is check that the `auth` cookie exists, not just any cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The way I logout my user is by creating a mutation called clearToken and commit to it in the action :

State :

```
token: null,
```

Mutations :

```
clearToken(state) {
    state.token = null
  },
```

Actions :

```
logout(context) {
    context.commit('clearToken')
    Cookie.remove('token')
}
```

This way, you token state revert back to null.